# Выход из приложения qt

Tags: qt, c++

Консольное приложение qt4.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    return app.quit();
    //return app.exec();
}
```

В консольном приложении мне цикл app.exec() не нужен. При попытке скомпилировать с return app.quit() или return app.exit() выходит ошибка: *error: void value not ignored as it ought to be*. Почему? И как корректно покинуть приложение в командной строке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так ведь написано же чёрным по белому:

> void value not ignored

Т.е. app.quit возвращает void, а вы его пытаетесь в int превратить.

Прочтите про [quit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#quit) и всё будет ясно. Вам придётся сделать

```
app.quit();
return 0;
```